# Python 3.6 TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I am improving my python using tasks on Codility and ran into a problem while completing the MaxCounter exercise.

This exercise gives an integer N and a list A where N is within the range [1..100,000] and each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..N + 1].

N represents N counters all beginning at 0 and each element in A represents an operation on the list of counters.  If A[i] <= N then the A[i]th counter is incremented +1 such that if A[i] = 1 then the 0th counter is incremented.  If A[i] == N + 1 then all of the counters are set the value of the current maximum.

After all actions are completed return the list of counters.

My code is as follows:

```
def solution(N, A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6

    counters = [0] * N


    for i in A:
        if i == N + 1:
            counters = max(counters) * N
        else:
            counters[i-1] += 1
    
    return counters


    pass
```

On the line "counters[i-1] += 1" I am receiving the error:

File "/tmp/solution.py", line 13, in solution
counters[i-1] += 1

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I am not sure why I am getting this error as I am not calling an integer as a list.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The error means that `counters` is an `int` object. Is it possible that in one of the 8 lines of code you assign an integer value to `counters`? Did you add a print statement in your code to see what `counters` is when you get this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your list counters is being set to an integer by the line `max(counters) * N` you need to change the variable name that this line is set to.

Comment: Thank you.  I forgot to put brackets around [max(counters)]*N and it all works now

Answer (score -1):

Counters is an integer and not a list, so it is not subscriptable.